# Alfresco and drupal integration

Tags: drupal, alfresco, cmis

I need steps to integrate alfresco 5.1 with drupal. I searched on the internet for the solution but did not find anything regarding it. There are many articles regarding why should we integrate but none on how should we do it.

I have to develop a content-oriented website and alfresco is needed to be used as ECMS. Are there any better approaches than using alfresco-drupal?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Various ways to integrate Alfresco and Drupal:

1) **Drupal Alfresco Module:** As Vishwanath mentioned you could go for any of these modules which provide readily integration of Alfresco with Drupal.[This module](https://www.drupal.org/project/alfresco) manages Alfresco content items as Drupal nodes using a custom content type (Alfresco item).

**Risk**: This may have not been updated,so might face some challenges when you try to use it with latest version.

2) **[RESTFul webservices](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/references/RESTful-intro.html)** : Provided by Alfresco for integration.It is easy to use and best suited for integration.

**RISK**: You need to develop your own set of webscripts apart from given webscripts when out of box webscripts does not meet your requirement.

3) **CMIS APIs**: Alfresco also supports [CMIS APIs](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/pra/1/topics/cmis-welcome.html) you could check out list of APIs given by alfresco and select the language of your choice to customize them.

**RISK**: You need to make yourself familiar with CMIS terminology and concepts.You will also have risk similar to REST webscript.

Answer (score 1):

For using alfresco there is a durpal contrib module URL: https://www.drupal.org/project/alfresco you can use this to integrate your drupal website with alfresco. Its stable in 6.x, if you want you can use 7.x dev release.

There are simillar modules for integration like URL: https://www.drupal.org/project/canopy

For more support you can join this group URL: https://groups.drupal.org/alfresco-integration